# ios - list items have text cut off after a certain length

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a list view that sometimes has long text. When the text is a few paragraphs, it tends to get cut off at some point. Part of the strange behavior is that it does not always get cut off at the same character, but kind of random.

Here is the code that I use to populate the list:

```
// CREATING EACH CELL IN THE LIST
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    //static const NSInteger kLabelTag = 1;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault)
            reuseIdentifier:@"business"];

    NSString *comment = [[items_array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:(@"comment")];
    NSString *first_name = [[items_array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:(@"first_name")];
    //Boolean *is_private = [[items_array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:(@"is_private")];

    // Creating a constraint size for the label you are making
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(320 - (10 * 2), 20000.0f); 

    // Determining the size that you will need for the label based on the comment
    // length and the contraint size
    CGSize size = [comment sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; 

    //  Creating the label and initializing it with the frame that you have
    //  determined by your size calculations above
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, MAX(size.height, 44.0f) + 20.0f)];

    // setting up the label properties
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

    standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *is_private = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"is_private"];

    if ( is_private == nil )
    {
        label.text = [first_name stringByAppendingString:[@": "  stringByAppendingString:comment]]; // comment;
    }
    else
    if ( [is_private isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        label.text = [first_name stringByAppendingString:[@": "  stringByAppendingString:comment]]; // comment;     
    }
    else 
    {
        label.text = comment;  
    }

    // adding the label view to the cell that you have created
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];        

    // CLOSE THE SPINNER
    [spinner stopAnimating];

    // return the cell for the table view
    return cell;
}

//This method will determine how tall each row needs to be. Cell size for word wrapping.
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{    
    NSString *comment = [[items_array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:(@"comment")];

    // Again you are getting the constraints because you are going to us this size
    // to constrain the height of the cell just like you determined the size for the label.
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(320 - (10 * 2), 20000.0f);

    // Again, determining the size that we will need for the label, because it will drive
    // the height of the cell
    CGSize size = [comment sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; 

    //  Finally, we can determine the height for the cell!
    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

    //  return the height, which is the height of the label plus some extra space to make
    //  it look good.
    return height + (10 * 2);
}
```

Does this code have anything particularly incorrect with it? Or is the problem possibly rooted elsewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you create the label, you hand it a max height

```
MAX(size.height, 44.0f)
```

which means the label is never higher than 44 points.
If the text (which is being wrapped to fit the width of the label) is higher than the label, the lines that fallow below it will still be in the label, but not visible.

Your options :

-Make the label font auto sizing

-change the height, or switch to dynamic height for the label

this would go something like this every time you update it:

```
myLabel.text = @"some text";
CGRect rect = myLabel.frame;
rect.size.height = textView.contentSize.height;// Adding.size Since height is not a member of CGRect
textView.frame = rect; //your label is now as high as its contents (the text)
```

-trim the text that goes into the label so it never exceeds the height of the label.

Comment: I think changing the height to dynamic height for the label is probably best here.  Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: It's a little hard here because you're building your UI from code and not in the visual editor.
i'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

I would get rid of having your own UILabel unless absolutely necessary and dynamically adjust the cell's height based on the string size. Check out my example below:

**Create the strings before loading tableview**

```
-(void)createStrings{

    newArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(NSDictionary *dictionary in items_array){
        NSString *comment = [dictionary objectForKey:(@"comment")];
        NSString *first_name = [dictionary objectForKey:(@"first_name")];
        NSString *combinedString = [first_name  stringByAppendingString:[@": "  stringByAppendingString:comment]];
        [newArray addObject:combinedString];
    }

}

#pragma mark - Table View Data Source
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [newArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table View Delegate
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17];
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize labelSize = [[newArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        return labelSize.height + 30;
}
```